# Why does Travis-CI use 18 seconds to build a simple C code?

Tags: travis-ci

For a small C helloworld program, Travis-CI uses 18 seconds to build. Why is it so slow?  My files:

.travis.yml

```
language: C

script: make
```

Makefile

```
all:
    gcc hello.c
```

hello.c

```
int main(){

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't only have to build the C code. It also has to create the enviroment in which it has access to a C complier to build your code!

Creating this enviroment will take some time.